# PowerShell load app.config into current domain

Tags: powershell, app-config, appdomain, system.configuration

Got a bit of a query regarding loading a type that depends on a configuration file in PowerShell; I know you can load the file on the fly using the below with a fully qualified path:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData('APP_CONFIG_FILE', $appConfigPath.Path)
```

This is all fine and dandy; however the configuration file references *other* configuration files, which *aren't* loaded. File structure of my project like so:

- -MyPowerShellScript.ps1
- -app.config (with references to the configuration files in the ~/Config directory)
- -Config
- --*Other configuration files*

The other configuration files are referenced like so in the app.config (Examine is the type that's throwing the exception regarding missing configuration, actually):

```
<Examine configSource="config\ExamineSettings.config" />
```

Since PowerShell runs under ~\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0, **how would I go about loading these extraneous configuration files into the current domain?** Is this even possible or do I need to really re-think this? I even tried pasting the files directly into the PowerShell folder, which is pretty horrible!

Cheers - Mike